# Creating a gls from a spreadsheet

Tags: glossaries, conversion

I have a spreadsheet of 1925 terms that I wish to build a glossary for. Short of manually adding tags to each line and exporting to a plain text file, is there a way to convert the spreadsheet into a gls file?

The spreadsheet has each term split into separate columns for the term, its type (noun, verb, etc.) and defintion.

Comment: I guess, this depends on the spreadsheet format, perhaps it should first be exported to pure `ASCII` format and then processed with `perl` to produce a glossary file.

Comment: Addendum: Perhaps, you should have a look on the `datatool` package, especially on `datagidx.sty`

Answer (score 7):

Suppose your spreadsheet looks something like:

[image: Image of spreadsheet with four columns]

**Method 1:**

Export the spreadsheet to CSV. For example, `sample.csv`:

```
Name,Type,Past Tense,Description
sit,verb,sat,rest on one's hind quarters
cat,noun,---,small domesticate feline animal
mat,noun,---,floor covering
the,determiner,---,the definite article
```

Now you can use a combination of [`datatool`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatool) and [`glossaries`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\DTLloaddb{data}{sample.csv}

% Ensure these fields are expanded
\glssetexpandfield{name}
\glssetexpandfield{desc}
\glssetexpandfield{descplural}
\glssetexpandfield{sortvalue}
\glssetexpandfield{symbol}

\DTLforeach*{data}% data set
 {% assignments
  \Name=Name,%
  \Type=Type,%
  \PastTense=Past Tense,%
  \Desc=Description%
 }
 {%
   \newglossaryentry{\Name}{name={\Name},description={\Desc},%
   symbol={\Type},user1={\PastTense}}%
 }

\newcommand*{\glstype}{\glssymbol}
\newcommand*{\glspast}{\glsuseri}

\begin{document}

\Gls{the} \gls{cat} \glspast{sit} on \gls{the} \gls{mat}.

\printglossary[style=index]

\end{document}
```

This requires: `(pdf)latex` + `makeglossaries` + `(pdf)latex` to create:

[image: Image of resulting document]

**Method 2:**

Convert the spreadsheet to a `.dbtex` file using [`datatooltk`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatooltk) either via the GUI (`datatooltk-gui`) or via the command line:

```
datatooltk --xls sample.xls --output sample.dbtex
```

The document is only slightly different from the first method above:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\DTLloaddbtex{\mydata}{sample.dbtex}

% Ensure these fields are expanded
\glssetexpandfield{name}
\glssetexpandfield{desc}
\glssetexpandfield{descplural}
\glssetexpandfield{sortvalue}
\glssetexpandfield{symbol}

\DTLforeach*{\mydata}% data set
 {% assignments
  \Name=Name,%
  \Type=Type,%
  \PastTense=Past Tense,%
  \Desc=Description%
 }
 {%
   \newglossaryentry{\Name}{name={\Name},description={\Desc},%
   symbol={\Type},user1={\PastTense}}%
 }

\newcommand*{\glstype}{\glssymbol}
\newcommand*{\glspast}{\glsuseri}

\begin{document}

\Gls{the} \gls{cat} \glspast{sit} on \gls{the} \gls{mat}.

\printglossary[style=index]

\end{document}
```

The result is the same, but with a large database (such as yours) the document will compile faster.